# CollapsingToolbar in "normal" layout?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, toolbar

I want to create something like the CollapsingToolbar in my "normal layout". It should be added to a RecyclerView. Is this possible? Because I like the cool resize and animation!

It should be something like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <MagicCollapsingItemThatINeed
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </MagicCollapsingItemThatINeed>

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is "normal layout" in your context. Are you talking [about this control](https://crazyaboutandroid.wordpress.com/2015/05/)

Comment: @j2ko yes, I want this CollapsingToolbar effect in a RecyclerView. Because I only know, that this effect is available for the toolbar.

Comment: `RecyclerView` should not have any children declared in XML.

Comment: @Karakuri Ohh yes, I know. But I just wanted to show how I want it. I would do it with an Adapter.